# How can I calculate the height at which the mobile phone is located?

Tags: signal-power, parameter-estimation

I need to calculate Hm - the height at which the mobile phone is located.
For calculating I can use:

- Hb - the BTS height, m
- L - the rssi-parameter, dB,
- f - frequency, MHz.
  When I use an Okuruma-Hata model's expression , I get abnormal data.

May be you know any other expressions for calculating the height at which the mobile phone is located?

Answer (score 1):

That model is used to estimate path loss based on distance and frequency (applicable to RF frequencies from 150 to 1500 MHz). Since there are an infinite number of heights that would resolve to the same distance, you cannot use the formula with the transmission from a single BTS to resolve the mobile height.

You could theoretically triangulate this with multiple transmissions from multiple base stations but given the variance in the actual land-based propagation models there would be significant challenges in achieving any sort of reasonable accuracy.

Why not use GPS since nearly every mobile has a GPS receiver now?

Comment: For calculating I can use: Hb - the BTS height, L - the rssi-parameter, and f . GPS is unavailable. Do you know any other expressions for calculation?

Comment: @Natal04ka You see from the simple geometry of it how there is no unique solution possible from those parameters correct?  You can essentially be on the surface of a sphere with that same path loss. If you know the BTS geographic location and your handsets geographic location you can then reduce your possible solutions.